# grails - error executing bootstrap (Error creating bean with name 'messageSource')

Tags: grails

I made some seemingly harmless changes (added a few domain classes, added the plugin shopping-cart), and now apparently the BootStrap.groovy class doesn't execute at all.

While I made a few changes to BootStrap.groovy, I restored a previously good file that works fine, dumbfounded by the error.  Also, in the good (old) BootStrap.groovy, I put some println statements at the top of the init action, but those aren't printing out and don't seem to even be reached.  Finally, I did an uninstall of the plugin, and after that, deleted the shopping-cart plugin folder manually.

Do you know what this error is, or have any debug guidance?  (am running Grails 1.3.7)

```
Running Grails application..
Configuring Spring Security ...
Configuring Spring Security UI ...
```

> 2011-12-09 13:51:33,036 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -
>   Error executing   bootstraps: Error creating bean with name
>   'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type
>   [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped.
>   Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type
>   (String, Integer etc.)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type
>   [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped.
>   Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type
>   (String, Integer etc.)    at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.startSecure(TomcatServer.groovy:289)
>     at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$startSecure.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:152)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)    at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:66)     at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:30)    at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)   at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)    at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)   at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property
>   'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type
>   [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped.
>   Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type
>   (String, Integer etc.)    ... 24 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type
>   [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped.
>   Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type
>   (String, Integer etc.)    ... 24 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Type [null] is not a basic type or a
>   domain class and cannot be mapped. Either specify a type within the
>   [mapping] block or use a basic type (String, Integer etc.)    ... 24
>   more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I tried the "help" and to get the above into a single code block, so I wouldn't have to indent every line, but the help mechanism explained didn't seem to work ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed all the new domain classes and references to them, and the error went away.  I'll update this as soon as I figure out what the problem is, hopefully not related to a domain change to one of the Spring Security classes (User).

Ok, the problem is/was, I had an enum declaration at the top of one of the domain classes I added.  If I move the enum declaration below the class declaration, then all is good.  I imagine this is a hibernate error / problem?

Comment: The key line of your message starts with `nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException` and goes on to state that Grails/Hibernate was having trouble mapping your Enum/Domain class to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have a problem in one of your domain classes where you use a "def" or some other invalid type in the domain class for one of the fields.